# How to send Celery task from one machine to another?

Tags: python, redis, celery

I am trying to send a task from celery worker on Machine A to celery worker on Machine B with the help of "task name".

All the tasks are defined on Machine B, and only one task is on Machine A. I'd like to pass a task_name to Machine A worker and execute the task with the same task_name on Machine B.

How do I communicate with one another.

Do we keep the same broker_url in both the workers or what?

I am using Redis as the Broker url and result backend.

Answer (score 4):

(1) you can do this with separate brokers for Machine A and Machine B.  redis, by default, usually gives you sixteen databases, numbered 0-15.  So you can very easily assign db 0 to use for the broker for A and assign db 1 for the broker for B.  Then to send a task from B to A, you can use `send_task`:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('redis://myredis-server:6379/0')
app.send_task('task_name', kwargs={ 'param1': 'value1' })
```

(2) you can also do this with one broker if you use separate celery queues.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll try the same as soon as possible.

Comment: So I used the second method with broker_url same on both the machines, and different queues. When I used send_task from machine A, it did not reflect on the machine B, but it did on machine A when I created a new task with same name as on Machine B. 
Also, when starting the workers, it shows
..Info] mingle: searching for neighbors
..Info] mingle: all alone.

Shouldn't it show that there is another worker running with the same broker_url?

Comment: And the first method, I am using two different databases, hosted at different places, and can't seem to get how exactly is it supposed to be used. If you can help with it or refer me a good source to look at?

Comment: The second method worked like a charm when I used AMQP instead of Redis.